# Поддерживает ли ViewPager2 Margins?

Tags: android

activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime_pager);

        UUID crimeId = (UUID) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CRIME_ID);

        mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(this).getCrimes();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        mViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.crime_view_pager);

        mViewPager2.setAdapter(new FragmentStateAdapter(this) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
                Log.d("qwer", Integer.toString(position));
                return CrimeFragment.newInstance(mCrimes.get(position).getId());
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return mCrimes.size();
            }
        });

        for(int i = 0; i < mCrimes.size(); i++)
            if(mCrimes.get(i).getId().equals(crimeId))
                mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(i,false);

    }
```

activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/crime_view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>
```

fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

...

</LinearLayout>
```

Вывод:

[image]

Насколько я зная `ViewPager2` внутренне это обычный `RecyclerView` который поддерживает поля(margins), но как вы можете видеть поля данного фрагмента отсутствуют несмотря на то, что в xml файле я указал 8dp. **Почему так? Поддерживает ли ViewPager2 Margins и если да то что я сделал не так?**

Comment: А padding-ом пробовал решить проблему?

Comment: @Михаил нет, но даже если padding поможет, мне всё равно интересно почему margins не работают. ведь они должны

Comment: во view классах каких только багов не встретишь) Чтоб понять - надо смотреть исходники - разбиратся (можно глянуть программно какой маржин у liner, попробывать программно задать и опять же проверить)

Comment: @Михаил мне кажется дело в FragmentStateAdapter потому что я попробовал написать свой adapter где в каждом viewholder просто лежит линер со всеми виджетами и в этом случае margins появились